# discord.py-Cannot send a message copy from one server to another specific server

Tags: python, discord.py, nonetype

Whenever I try to run my code I get the following error. I have rechecked my channel ID several times and also enabled Privileged Gateway Intents from discord developer panels. Bot has administrator power so that shouldn't be an issue. I am using replit as my IDE.
Please help

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 28, in on_message
    await general.send (**message.content + ' . ' +message.author.name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Code for the bot is as follows:

```
import os
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members= True
client= discord.Client( intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('i am ready ')

my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  
  if message.author== client.user:
    return
  if message.content.startswith('$work'):
    general = client.get_channel(849317968193912842)
    await general.send (**message.content + ' . ' +message.author.name)

  if message.content.startswith('tesla'):
    await message.channel.send('elon musk' )


client.run(my_secret)
```

Comment: Why do you have `**` in the code? What do you want to achieve with `message.content`?

Comment: error shows that `general` is `None` so it couldn't get this channel. Did you try with string `"849317968193912842"` instead of integer?

Comment: if I uses my channel ID then it works even without `intents` or other changes in settings.

Comment: @furas, get_channel always uses an id, so string wouldn’t work here

Comment: @PranjalSingh Correct this line: `await general.send (**message.content + ' . ' +message.author.name)`. It is incorrectly stated. Remove the space between the parentheses and remove the `**` as well.

Comment: @BhavyadeepYadav I tried this still it returns the same error `await general.send(message.content + message.author.name)`

Comment: @Dominik I dont know much about kwargs and I was experenting with them based on an article. I thought that may help. I removed the `**`, still I get the same error.

Comment: all your problem is that you don't have privileges to access this channel and `get_channel()` gives `None` - and later you have `None.send()` - so your real problem is not `send` but `get_channel`. And all changes in `send` can't resolve this problem. But I don't know how to access this channel. I have no problem when I use my own channel (and I don't need to use `intents` for this)

Comment: @furas would increasing scope of the application under Oauth2 in discord developer dashboard help?

Comment: if it is your channel then you could access it without any changes. Or maybe it is not channel number.